# "Extern" with DirectX variables?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10

For some reason, whenever I declare a directx variable as extern, I receive a linking error.

Example:

In some header file:

```
extern ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* pWorldVariable;
```

In some other cpp file where I include the .h file containing pd3dDevice:

```
pWorldVariable = NULL;
```

An error similar to this will pop up:

> 2>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable * pProjectionVariable" (?pProjectionVariable@@3PAUID3D10EffectMatrixVariable@@A)
>   2>C:\Users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Shyr\Debug\Shyr.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

The minute I take away the `extern` declaration, it compiles like a charm. Of course, I'm actually wanting to reference several variables, such as my swap chain, device, target view, etc from a dll I'm working on. Anybody know what's up?

(Also, YES, it only declared once)

Just to prove that the issue is isolated to DirectX variables, I made an extern variable "george" and initialized it to 4. I then referenced it elsewhere and changed the value. Compiled just fine.

Comment: The error message complains about pProjectionVariable, not pWorldVariable.  Nevertheless, a *definition* is required.

Comment: That looks to certainly be the issue. I was switching up so many variables trying to figure out what's wrong that I didn't realize that I copied the wrong error. That said, the error is identical for all the weird directx linking errors. When they're declared and defined, it works. That said - how could you define something like a swap chain externally? It requires zeroing out memory and doing a bunch of other definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was running across was a matter of not understanding extern declaration vs. definition. This answer helps, but you have to read the whole thing and then do some research to understand it:

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Answer (score 2):

`extern` is used to declare a sort of **reference** to a variable that is used externally across source files (i.e. You declare the variable normally and in each file you use it you have to declare an **internal** reference to it using `extern`)

You have to declare the variable in a source file as well.

Example.cpp

```
ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable* pWorldVariable = 0;
```

YetAnotherFile.cpp

```
extern ID3D10EffectMatrixVariable * pWorldVariable;
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I've used extern other ways before and I just tried it by keeping it a standard variable, then referenced it in another file as extern and the error still appeared.

Comment: You should declare the variable in the source file not in the header file. If not, give it a shot.

Comment: It is not because of DirectX types. DirectX structs are simply user-defined entities, they don't receive any "special" treatment by the linker.